# mysql refference key issue, phpmyadmin error code 150

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, key, mysql-error-150

I am trying to create two table as below,

```
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT,   `UserType` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,   `FirstName`
varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,   `LastName` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,  
`Email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,   `CompanyName` varchar(64) DEFAULT
NULL,   `Telephone` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,   `Country` varchar(64)
DEFAULT NULL,   `Website` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,   `JobTitle`
varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,   `Active` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,   `Notes`
text,   `DateOfRegistration` datetime DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
(`Id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `login`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login` (   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`Username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `Email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,  
`Password` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   `FailedAttemptCount` int(2) NOT
NULL,   `LastLogin` datetime NOT NULL,   `UserLevel` int(1) NOT NULL, 
`IsVerified` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `VerificationKey`
varchar(256) NOT NULL,   `VerifiKeyCreated` datetime NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),   FOREIGN KEY (`Id`) REFERENCES users.Id,   UNIQUE
KEY `username` (`Username`),   UNIQUE KEY `Email` (`Email`) )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to add a foreign key i.e. login.Id references users.Id, but I am getting error(code 150) in phpmyadmin.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best Regards,
Rajib

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a simple typographical error. It should be `FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES users(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
REFERENCES `users`(`Id`)
```

instead of

```
REFERENCES users.Id
```

cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html